# custom uislider on xcode

Tags: swift, uislider

i learning swift. i have a question.
how to create like this, bubble label always follow slider circle, also when they press + slider also change +1(label also change +1), so do the - button:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/2ztfudi.jpg]

static label change when slider value change are:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    stepper.value = Double(currentValue)
    labelku.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

static label change when stepper value change are:

```
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    var stepperValue = Int(sender.value)
    slider.value = Float(stepperValue)
    labelku.text = Int(sender.value).description
}
```

edited: i put the bubble syntax in each ibaction, so everytime currentValue or stepperValue change, the bubble change its position

edited:here is the long code to did that, but it could be shorter. it is up to you. i like longer one :)

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    stepper.value = Double(currentValue)
    labelku.text = "\(currentValue)"
    if(currentValue == 0 || currentValue == 1 || currentValue == 2 || currentValue == 3 || currentValue == 4 || currentValue == 5 || currentValue == 6){
        self.catImageView.hidden = false
        self.catImageView2.hidden = true
        self.catImageView3.hidden = true
        let catImages1 = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "ra_tr_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView.animationImages = catImages1
        self.catImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView.startAnimating()
    }else if(currentValue == 7 || currentValue == 8){
        self.catImageView.stopAnimating()
        self.catImageView.hidden = true
        self.catImageView2.hidden = false
        self.catImageView3.hidden = true
        let catImages2 = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "ra_av_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView2.animationImages = catImages2
        self.catImageView2.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView2.startAnimating()
    }else if(currentValue == 9 || currentValue == 10){
        self.catImageView2.stopAnimating()
        self.catImageView.hidden = true
        self.catImageView2.hidden = true
        self.catImageView3.hidden = false
        let catImages3 = (1...12).map { UIImage(named: "ra_ve_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView3.animationImages = catImages3
        self.catImageView3.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView3.startAnimating()
    }
    if(currentValue == 0){
        nomor0.hidden = false
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 1){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = false
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 2){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = false
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 3){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = false
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 4){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = false
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 5){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = false
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 6){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = false
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 7){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = false
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 8){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = false
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 9){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = false
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(currentValue == 10){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = false
    }
}
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    var stepperValue = Int(sender.value)
    //println(Int(sender.value))
    slider.value = Float(stepperValue)
    labelku.text = Int(sender.value).description
    if(stepperValue == 0 || stepperValue == 1 || stepperValue == 2 || stepperValue == 3 || stepperValue == 4 || stepperValue == 5 || stepperValue == 6){
        self.catImageView.hidden = false
        self.catImageView2.hidden = true
        self.catImageView3.hidden = true
        let catImages1 = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "ra_tr_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView.animationImages = catImages1
        self.catImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView.startAnimating()
    }else if(stepperValue == 7 || stepperValue == 8){
        self.catImageView.stopAnimating()
        self.catImageView.hidden = true
        self.catImageView2.hidden = false
        self.catImageView3.hidden = true
        let catImages2 = (1...6).map { UIImage(named: "ra_av_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView2.animationImages = catImages2
        self.catImageView2.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView2.startAnimating()
    }else if(stepperValue == 9 || stepperValue == 10){
        self.catImageView2.stopAnimating()
        self.catImageView.hidden = true
        self.catImageView2.hidden = true
        self.catImageView3.hidden = false
        let catImages3 = (1...12).map { UIImage(named: "ra_ve_\($0)")! }
        self.catImageView3.animationImages = catImages3
        self.catImageView3.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.catImageView3.startAnimating()
    }
    if(stepperValue == 0){
        nomor0.hidden = false
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 1){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = false
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 2){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = false
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 3){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = false
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 4){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = false
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 5){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = false
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 6){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = false
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 7){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = false
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 8){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = false
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 9){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = false
        nomor10.hidden = true
    }else if(stepperValue == 10){
        nomor0.hidden = true
        nomor1.hidden = true
        nomor2.hidden = true
        nomor3.hidden = true
        nomor4.hidden = true
        nomor5.hidden = true
        nomor6.hidden = true
        nomor7.hidden = true
        nomor8.hidden = true
        nomor9.hidden = true
        nomor10.hidden = false
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stepper.wraps = true
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.minimumValue = 0
    slider.minimumValue = 0
    stepper.maximumValue = 10
    slider.maximumValue = 10
    stepper.stepValue = 1
    stepper.value = 0
    slider.value = 0
    questionText.text = question.description
    
    self.catImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    self.catImageView.animationImages = getCatAnimation(labelku.tag)
    self.catImageView.startAnimating()
    
    answerLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    answerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.2
    answerLabel.layer.borderColor = ColorLightGreyForQuestion.CGColor
    answerLabel.text = placeHolderText
    
    self.answerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "buble.png")!)
    answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

hope it could help other.

regards.

Comment: if you are just learning, you should not start with a highly complex visual effect.

Comment: @holex, thanks for your comment. actually this is not highly complex visual effect. but now i already done it.

Answer (score 0):

You could trying using [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/), which is an app that turns drawings into code. It is perfect for the sort of thing you are trying to make. You can export into Swift (or Objective-C).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZVrc8Y67AI) is the best video I have found that explains PaintCode. PaintCode is free to try (pretty restrictive in that you can not open saved documents) and cost around $80 US.

*Edit*

This code created in 11min, 46seconds:

```
![func drawSlider(#value: CGFloat, textValue: String, leftText: String, rightText: String) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let color = UIColor(red: 0.170, green: 0.565, blue: 0.571, alpha: 1.000)
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.120, green: 0.635, blue: 0.521, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Variable Declarations
    let barWidth: CGFloat = value * 20
    let buttonPosition: CGFloat = 20 + value * 20
    let bubblePosition: CGFloat = value * 20 + 1

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(31, 96, 200, 4))
    UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()


    //// Rectangle 2 Drawing
    let rectangle2Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(31, 96, barWidth, 4))
    color.setFill()
    rectangle2Path.fill()


    //// Oval Drawing
    var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(buttonPosition, 88, 20, 19))
    color.setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()


    //// Group
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, bubblePosition, 19)



    //// Oval 2 Drawing
    var oval2Path = UIBezierPath()
    oval2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(35.42, 56.15))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(57, 28.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(47.81, 53.06), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(57, 41.85))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(28.5, 0), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(57, 12.76), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(44.24, 0))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 28.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(12.76, 0), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0, 12.76))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(23.94, 56.64), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0, 42.69), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(10.37, 54.45))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(29, 65), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(25.42, 56.88), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(27.45, 65))
    oval2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(35.42, 56.15), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(31.39, 65), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(33.2, 56.71))
    color2.setFill()
    oval2Path.fill()
    color.setStroke()
    oval2Path.lineWidth = 2
    oval2Path.stroke()


    //// Text Drawing
    let textRect = CGRectMake(9, 10, 40, 39)
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let textFontAttributes = \[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: ".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular", size: 34)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle\]

    let textTextHeight: CGFloat = NSString(string: textValue).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(textRect.width, CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textFontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextClipToRect(context, textRect);
    NSString(string: textValue).drawInRect(CGRectMake(textRect.minX, textRect.minY + (textRect.height - textTextHeight) / 2, textRect.width, textTextHeight), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)



    CGContextRestoreGState(context)


    //// Text 2 Drawing
    let text2Rect = CGRectMake(19, 113, 48, 29)
    let text2Style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
    text2Style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let text2FontAttributes = \[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: ".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: text2Style\]

    let text2TextHeight: CGFloat = NSString(string: leftText).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(text2Rect.width, CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: text2FontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextClipToRect(context, text2Rect);
    NSString(string: leftText).drawInRect(CGRectMake(text2Rect.minX, text2Rect.minY + (text2Rect.height - text2TextHeight) / 2, text2Rect.width, text2TextHeight), withAttributes: text2FontAttributes)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)


    //// Text 3 Drawing
    let text3Rect = CGRectMake(200, 113, 48, 29)
    let text3Style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
    text3Style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let text3FontAttributes = \[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: ".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: text3Style\]

    let text3TextHeight: CGFloat = NSString(string: rightText).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(text3Rect.width, CGFloat.infinity), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: text3FontAttributes, context: nil).size.height
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextClipToRect(context, text3Rect);
    NSString(string: rightText).drawInRect(CGRectMake(text3Rect.minX, text3Rect.minY + (text3Rect.height - text3TextHeight) / 2, text3Rect.width, text3TextHeight), withAttributes: text3FontAttributes)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}]
```

This code is totally untested...

[image: Preview in PaintCode]

There are four parameters;

1. the value of the slider (expecting 0 to 10)
2. the text value to put into the bubble
3. the left text
4. the right text

**Code Limitations** - it is a fixed width (200px). But this could be changed.

**Next steps**:

1. Create a custom view by extending a UIView
2. Create properties to represent the four variables
3. Call the above code from the draw method
4. Add your custom view to your UIViewController or whatever

Here is the [PaintCode file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71590109/Stackoverflow/SliderExample.pcvd) for reference.

Comment: paincode is awesome, but still confuse after watched the tutorial.

Comment: I am a developer who *likes* playing around with these sort of programs (Photoshop etc); it took me some time to "get" PainCode. I agree the tutorials are not the best. I wonder if you watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZVrc8Y67AI)?

Comment: maybe it seems silly, i sudenly got idea for my own question, i put it on edited at the question bottom. thanks lindon.

Comment: Did you end up using this? Or something else? If you used this, you can mark it as correct. If you used something else, you can make a note of what you did to help others :D

Comment: i end up use mine, like i wrote before. when a friend of mine come to my work desk, we were talking, suddenly i got an idea to put that inside ibaction. ok, i will make a note to help others.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer :)